# How to Combine Multiple Probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a list of many products, each with a given probability of the owner's gender and I'd like to compute the gender probability for users who have multiple products. I am forced to assume that the gender of the users is independent of the products or combinations (since I don't have any additional information).

For example:

```
Product A is purchased 60% of the time by females and 40% by males
Product B is purchased 80% of the time by females and 20% by males
```

**If I see a user with product A and B, what is the probability that the user is female? Male?**

I originally thought to average the probabilities, so in this case, it would lead to 70% probability of being female and 30% male. But this feels wrong, because of the following:

In the case where, for example, a person of unknown gender has 10 products that where each product is associated with a probability of that user being female equal to 90%, that the resultant probability of being female would just be 90%. It should be much higher...intuitively.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you don't have enough information to answer, because you have no information about *joint* purchases of the two products. For instance, possibly only males purchase them both or possibly only females.  You cannot rely on an independence assumption because your data show that gender is *not* independent of the products.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. Naive Bayes works well in certain circumstances, under the invalid presumption of independence. Any ideas if I can do something similar here?

Comment: I think you will get out of this exercise exactly what you put into it.  The data, it would seem, are going to tell you little if anything at all. It's just too easy to think of exceptions to any rule or assumption.  For instance, somebody buying one item of lingerie might very likely be female but someone buying three or more might be a (desperate) male.

Comment: you can calculate the probability using statistical permutation test if you have enough events.  10 should be sufficient if the probabilities are not too close (ie not .45 vs .55, but maybe .8 vs .20)